# How would I tell if a dealer sold me a refurbished appliance as new?

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

I've got a DOA fridge that I'm having to have a service tech come look at a second time. The dealer I bought it from has been *accused* of selling refurbished items as new in the past. How would a person actually go about finding that information out?

I noticed this stamp on the back. Do you suppose I'm getting excited about nothing?

[image: Back of refrigerator]

Comment: If you can find a plate with a manufacturing date that isn't close to Oct 2015, then the "fix..." is suspicious. Maybe contact the manufacturer with the serial number and see what they say.

Comment: You can Google "appliance serial number lookup" and find numerous sites that allow you to look up the manufacture date of your appliance.

Comment: Ah yes, looks like I'm (as I suspected) just having some bad luck. Somehow I missed the manufacture date on the label, even though it's clearly labelled "Manufacture date."

Comment: Seems like you figured this out, but for future reference, the "dox matrix" style of that "FIX" line is only produced by high-speed printing heads installed on large machines in a factory.  There's not really any way to print something like that outside of an industrial setting.

Comment: @JPhi1618 - Handheld inkjet printers are [readily](https://www.amazon.com/Handheld-Inkjet-Printer-Industrial-Coder/dp/B00GJMKCHE) [available](http://www.cycjet.com/product.asp?ClassCode=51). It's conceivable that a repair depot might use one to tag repaired products.

Comment: Ink jet hand held printers have been doing this for years, I used to work at HP in the inkjet group the printer is fairly small and uses an encoder to space the dots, they are in use by many smaller companies. The one in the link is quite large compared to the one we had but they are out there.

Answer (score 1):

Completely new appliances come with packing materials. Everything from the box to the instructions sealed in a plastic bag. Stainless surfaces will have protective plastic films that are removed after delivery and installation. Shipping blocks and moveable parts taped so that they do not move while being transported.

Answer (score 0):

What does the receipt say? Look up the model and check manufacturing schedule and see if it is still be manufacturing. Also apply for a factory warranty, that will be very enlightening if used.  Look for signs of wear etc, discolored heating elements, dirt in condenser of refrigeration equipment.